# Adding to select not working by taught += method

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues with adding to a select using the method we are taught:

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/gbc3q3sz/ this is my version of it, Using the example above, But the select box is never filled out even though `console.log(document.forms[0]["weapons"])` returns the right tag

The code:

html:

```
<body onLoad="OnLoad()">
<form>
    <select name="weapons" onChange="SelectWeapon()"></select>
</form>
```

js:

```
var weaponsArray = [
    'Broadsword',
    'Crossbow',
    'Magic staff'
];


function OnLoad()
{
    for (i = 0; i < weaponsArray.length; i++) {
        var weapTag = "<option value='"+ i +"'>"+ weaponsArray[i] +"</option>";

        console.log(document.forms[0]["weapons"]);
        document.forms[0]["weapons"] += weapTag;


    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, what is your source material?

Comment: @JamesThorpe From a university lecture

Comment: Let's hope that University teaches other things than JavaScript...

Comment: Maybe a mistake : `document.forms[0]["weapons"].innerHTML += weapTag;`

Comment: I'm wondering if this is something very non-standard that used to work in an old version of IE perhaps.  It's certainly not going to work properly on the modern web.

Comment: @Fefux Perhaps, yes

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I think that's likely, although I just tried it (http://output.jsbin.com/doxemipevo) with IE8, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Fefux 'TypeError: document.forms[0].weapons.innerHTML is not a function' Yeah, going to have to avoid this University's "method" completely

Comment: @TristanCunningham: `innerHTML` is a property, not a method. It works quite well for most things (although using `+=` with it is an anti-pattern), but it's not very surprising that it doesn't work for adding options to a `select`.

Comment: @TristanCunningham: I didn't write `document.forms[0]["weapons"].innerHTML() += weapTag`

Comment: @Fefux Sorry, meant it as going to avoid the way university taught us, Used it as a property in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because the code is written as though it were appending to a **string** defining a `select` box (e.g., `"<select>..."`); but what it's actually doing is trying to append to an **existing** `select` box, an `HTMLSelectElement`. You can't use string concatenation to do that (at least, not reliably cross-browser). I'm afraid the example pictured at the top of your question is simply incorrect; it *may* work for some browsers, but it's definitely not at all the right way to do this.

You can readily add elements by using `options.add` and the `Option` constructor:

```
function OnLoad()
{
    var options = document.forms[0].weapons.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < weaponsArray.length; i++) {
        options.add(new Option(weaponsArray[i], i));
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
var weaponsArray = [
    'Broadsword',
    'Crossbow',
    'Magic staff'
];

function OnLoad()
{
    var options = document.forms[0].weapons.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < weaponsArray.length; i++) {
        options.add(new Option(weaponsArray[i], i));
    }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="OnLoad()">
<form>
    <select name="weapons" onChange="SelectWeapon()"></select>
</form>
```

---

Side note: Note the `var` I added in front of `i` in the `Onload` code. Your previous code was falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. It's important to declare your variables.

Comment: OPs code appears to match the given sample - which itself seems horrible, hence me asking where it came from...

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Quite so.